# How to interactively pass values between Ansible and Jenkins while the Job is Running

Tags: jenkins, input, ansible, interactive, rm

My Jenkins UI takes parameter a list of files/folders along with wildcards from users that they wish to delete.

Jenkins then passes the files to be deleted across all hosts by invoking ansible-playbook.

My requirement is to prompt user on Jenkins for confirmation before deleting a file / folder.

Thus, how `rm -rfi /tmp/moht /var/log*/data.dat` prompts interactively asking the user confirmation before deleting the files; is what I Wish to prompt on Jenkins for each Host.

Thus, for the above I expect Jenkins to prompt like below:

```
Are you sure you want to delete 
/tmp/moht 
/var/log14Mar/data.dat
```

I'm aware of `input` function in Jenkins for prompt.

I'm also aware of an ansible `command` module that can be used to fire `rm -rfi` command.

I'm also aware of how to timeout or terminate the Jenkins Job upon user input. However, in this case I would love if the user input `Yes / No` could be sent back to the target host via ansible and action gets performed accordingly.

I understand that this may be too much an ask but other feasible solutions or suggestions are also appreciated.

Can you please suggest how can I achieve the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly feel that using Jenkins as interactive tool is a bad idea. But if you really like to implement bad ideas with unsuitable tools, you can try to use matrix job [1] based on files you want to remove.

Jenkins will create a list of jobs with a job for each file you'd like to remove. You ask confirmation and then execute an Ansible playbook to remove a file.

[1] https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-project/

It's horribly inefficient and you should not do it like this.